# JSpinners with shared SpinnerModel

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I'm trying to set up multiple JSpinners to edit a single Date value - i.e. one spinner for days, one for months, etc.

It seems like I ought to be able to share a single `SpinnerModel` between several JSpinners, but I'm running into difficulties with this approach.

What I tried was essentially as follows:

```
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
JSpinner dayPeer = new JSpinner(model);
dayPeer.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(dayPeer, "dd"));
JSpinner monthPeer = new JSpinner(model);
monthPeer.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(monthPeer, "MM"));
```

When doing this, I found that changing one value reset the other one. The problem seemed to originate in `JSpinner.DefaultEditor.propertyChange()`, which parses the editor text into a date, then calls `setValue()` with that.

So, it looks like I also need to implement a custom editor component with a custom `propertyChange()` method. Am I finally on the right track, or have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the `CyclingSpinnerListModel` found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#model) will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [`JCalendar`](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) and these related topics [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar). It has excellent date spinner support.

```
JSpinnerDateEditor jsde = new JSpinnerDateEditor();
JDateChooser spinner = new JDateChooser(jsde);
this.add(spinner);
```

Addendum: As an alternative, instead of separate spinners, consider using the `increment` and `decrement` actions bound to the standard [`JSpinner.DateEditor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.DateEditor.html).

Comment: Appreciate the pointer, but my employer would prefer to avoid using external libraries, even GLPL ones.